# Assigning type interface to an instance of a class implementing interface with added properties

Tags: typescript

I'm not sure if my question is clear, so I'll try to elaborate.
Say I have a class `MyClass` that implements an interface `MyInterface`. Apart from the properties required by the implementation (in this case, `myProp1`), it has an additional property `myProp2` as shown in the snippet below:

```
interface MyInterface {
  myProp1: string;
}

class MyClass implements MyInterface {
  myProp2 = '2';
  constructor(public myProp1: string) {}
}
```

Then, upon creating an instance of the class, I assigned it the `MyInterface` type. TypeScript doesn't complain even though `instance` has properties not specified in `MyInterface`:

```
let instance: MyInterface = new MyClass('1'); // no type error
```

But when attempting to access the added property (`myProp2`), I get an error:

```
console.log(instance.myProp2); // 'myProp2' does not exist on type 'MyInterface'. Did you mean 'myProp1'?
```

Is this a bug, or is it the intended behavior here?

Comment: You annotated the variable as having type `MyInterface` so it is treated as having only the attributes defined in `MyInterface`. If you don't add the annotation the type will be correctly inferred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working as intended.  TypeScript has [structural subtyping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system), which means that a value of type `X` is assignable to a variable of type `Y` if every member required in type `Y` is present in type `X`.

So all that's needed for a value to be a valid `MyInterface` is for it to have a `myProp1` property of type `string`.  And every instance of `MyClass` does have such a property (which is why `implements MyInterface` compiles without error), so according to TypeScript, it's perfectly fine to assign a `MyClass` instance to a variable of type `MyInterface`.

It is true that TypeScript sometimes does complain about extra properties, via [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks), but this only triggers in certain circumstances; in particular if you assign an [*object literal*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) with more properties than expected.  Since the expression`new MyClass('1')` is not an object literal, there is no warning.  This is described as being intentional in [microsoft/TypeScript#5303](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5303).

---

Furthermore, the compiler does not keep track of what's been assigned to a variable of a non-[union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).  The type of `instance` is the non-union `MyInterface` type, and so the assignment `instance = new MyClass('1')` does not change that. It is *not* [narrowed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) to `MyClass`, and thus you cannot access the `myProp2` property through `instance` (as `MyInterface` has no known `myProp2` property).

Note that this differs from the behavior on *union*-typed variables, where [assignments will narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments) the variable to just those union members with which the assigned value is compatible:

```
let instance: MyClass | Date = new MyClass('1');
instance.myProp2; // okay
```

---

This means that you really don't want to [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) a variable's type with a non-union type unless you want that variable to take on different values of that type and you don't need to keep track of which value it has.  If `instance` will always be an instance of `MyClass` and that's all you need to know, then you can annotate it as such:

```
let instance: MyClass = new MyClass('1');
instance.myProp2; // okay
```

or don't annotate it at all and let the compiler [infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) its type to be `MyClass`:

```
let instance = new MyClass('1');
instance.myProp2; // okay
```

Generally speaking it's a good idea to let the compiler infer types for you and only annotate things if you need to exert more control than inference gives you.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwChlkBbdABSgHsAHARgC5kBnMKUAcwG4iBfIkQQAbOK1Zp0AYTETkwMnREQyEcJIzZIsRCmKkK1egCZkAXmQByE1b6kENEOygBXBGBpQAFHVcAjEWAEcipaRhYXbgBKQmRBQSEVMAVnMDgQJBYtHF18SxAIAHcpWXFWbysGK2ieZAB6euQQGmQwdDoUaFooYSdWGhUAOhEaLm9QdgykIaNwk1qGpqs50ytkABMaCEkWlIgAD2B2ZCc2jpQrHMgkiBTJ9MyIE2yZOUkAH2QAEThIC2axVK70q1VqRAe02eszCpjqjVOAGs4Ohbvc0lCAMyvMryApAjC4ipVGp8SFPTEw4x0Ezwpo0ZGoojJVJTJ4AFgBhRKhJBJPB5KQ7Kp8zpSJRQA)

Comment: Thank you, I was wondering why this behavior was different from that of object literals.